# After importing procs from a namespace with force option, the procs in the global namespace are used by the auto_load in certain conditions

Tags: namespaces, tcl, autoload

I've been working on a project where scripts are written for a single hardware (say Type A) and have lot of procs very specific for that particular hardware. And now when I'm trying use the same scripts for a new hardware (say Type B) I thought of the following approach,

1. Re-define all the procs in a new library file within a new namespace.
2. When the main script starts check the hardware type.

   a. If type A do nothing. The procs from the global namespace (legacy) gets used

   b. If type B do a "namespace import -force" from the library to the global namespace.

The problem here is, the project uses auto_load so when I'm importing from the new library the legacy procs are not in the context yet. When a proc that is common to both the hardwares is called and if the file containing this proc also has another proc that was redefined for Type B, then that proc gets overwritten by the global namespace proc (legacy Type A) even though I have done a force import earlier.

If the wordings are difficult to follow, refer the below sample code and it's output. If the dummy proc is moved from TypeB.tcl to a new file, then there is no issue.

```
[wizard @ work]$ cat main.tcl
#!/usr/bin/tclsh
auto_mkindex ./
set auto_path "$auto_path ./"
namespace import -force TypeB::*
print_name
dummy
print_name

[wizard @ work]$ cat TypeA.tcl

proc print_name { } {
   puts "From the TypeA"
}
proc dummy {} {
   puts "Do nothing"
}

[wizard @ work]$ cat TypeB.tcl
namespace eval TypeB {
   namespace export *

   proc print_name {} {
      puts "From the TypeB"
   }

}


[wizard @ work]$ ./main.tcl
From the TypeB
Do nothing
From the TypeA
[wizard @ work]$
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider what `auto_mkindex` does: it creates a `tclIndex` file that contains

```
set auto_index(print_name) [list source [file join $dir TypeA.tcl]]
set auto_index(dummy) [list source [file join $dir TypeA.tcl]]
set auto_index(::TypeB::print_name) [list source [file join $dir TypeB.tcl]]
```

When you `namespace import TypeB::*`, then tcl executes `source [file join $dir TypeB.tcl]` and the `print_name` proc is pulled into the global namespace.

What happens when you call `dummy`? this: `source [file join $dir TypeA.tcl]` -- that pulls the `dummy` proc into the global namespace. But at the same time, the `print_name` proc is *redefined*.

At this point, you can still call `TypeB::print_name`

You'll  have to do one of:

- restructure your code,
- re-execute the `namespace import TypeB::*`, or
- be very careful about the order in which you call things, for instance by calling `dummy` *first*.

Comment: This sort of thing is why I prefer to not use autoloading in my code, together with the fact that defining procedures is _really fast_. I remember measuring how long it took back in the mid-1990s and deciding that loading everything up front was worth the time. Computers are enormously faster now…

Comment: I've never been that keen on autoloading. It's too magical for me. I much prefer explicitly requiring a package

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks for the answer. I understood the working and was more like recording my findings. I already restructured the code to work in a deterministic way.   However I was originally expecting the namespace force import to override the auto_load when source is called for file TypeA.tcl. (Regardless of the order in which these two actions happen)